# Given multiple posets, what is the probability that a randomly selected (uniform dist) subposet of their product has a max under the product order?

Tags: pr.probability, posets, products

Given multiple totally ordered posets, how do I find the probability that a randomly selected (with uniform distribution) subposet of their product has a maximum under the product order?

I have some vague intuition about the shape of subsets of powers of the unit interval that suggests that it is a relatively small probability, but nothing concrete.

I have no real idea on how to approach the problem after taking the power set of the product. I don't know a general way to separate members of the power set that have maximums under the product ordering fro. Those that don't without manually checking.

Suggestions for relevant texts are appreciated as well.

Comment: I take it these are finite posets? So you’re asking what is the probability that a uniformly random subposet of a product of chains (say of sizes $n_1,\ldots,n_k$) has a maximum? Reasonable question, but you might want to edit the post and especially the title (which vaguely says “multiple posets”) to reflect this.

Comment: I don't see why they should be finite. You can have maximums in posets of infinite cardinality.

Comment: But how do you define a uniform distribution on subposets otherwise?

Comment: I have no idea. If that assumption is necessary, then so be it. But I'd prefer not to make that assumption if possible.  The example in my head is [0,1]×[0,1]. Can we not define a uniform distribution for picking out subsets of [0,1]×[0,1] with a given property?

Comment: There is no “uniform” distribution on any infinite sets.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for dragging this out, but I'm not super familiar with measures and probability, so I might be using the wrong words. I'll try to explain differently. Say we have the product of 3 chains. We take the power set of this product and put each element in a hat so that all elements are equally likely to be chosen. I'm trying to find out how to find the probability that the element pulled out of the hat has a maximum using the product order. If that's only possible with finite chains, ok. If I'm using words wrong, ok. Just let me know how to edit the title and question and I will. Thanks

Comment: If you’re considering *finite* chains, then what you just wrote is a totally reasonable question in combinatorial probability. I would be shocked if it had a nice explicit answer, but you could reasonably ask for bounds on this probability.

Comment: Note that a special case of your question (when the chains are 2 element chains) is: choose a collection of subsets of some fixed finite set uniformly at random among all such collections: what’s the probability that one set in this collection contains all the others? That might be a question that has been studied. As you suggested, surely it is quite low probability, but people in probability do often like to study ‘rare’ events.